# How to handle dynamic URL in Jmeter?

Tags: url, jmeter

How to handle dynamic URL in Jmeter?

Once click on link, system generating dynamic number at the end of the URL, can anybody help me on it?

```
/invoicingapi/list-settings?filter[userSlug]=admin&filter[listId]=billing_item_aggregation_list&_=151366139361
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question about what you are trying to acoomplish

Comment: Hi, I want to handle last numeric value through Jmeter as it always change once user re-login to the application. As I'm not aware how to handle dynamic change number.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this dynamic number using JMeter's Regular Expression Extractor.

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Field to check: `URL`
   - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
   - Regular Expression: `billing_item_aggregation_list&_=(\d+)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image: JMeter Regular Expressions Extract Part of URL]
3. You will be able to access extracted value as `${id}` where required.

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)
- [Using Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/using-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Comment: Whenever I'm executing getting this value "N%2FA" instead of proper value.